# How can we export shared Store, Actions, Reducers and Services to a different module? - Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-module

Store, Actions, Reducers and some Services are in a separate shared module - suppose that module is shared.module.ts. If we want to use all these entities from a different module, how can we export it? I know we can export a component to other modules, but what about these? If I trigger an action from a different module, will it trigger a reducer in the shared module? Specific to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { RouterState, StoreRouterConnectingModule } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { reducers, metaReducers } from './app.state';  

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ routerState: RouterState.Minimal}),
        // Instrumentation must be imported after importing StoreModule (config is optional)
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
            maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
            logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
            autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
        }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([
            // your effects here
        ]),
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [],
    entryComponents: [],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Then import it in another module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [SharedModule],
    exports: [],
    bootstrap: [],
})
export class CustomersModule {}
```

Comment: Hi dopoto, thank you for your answer! I am exactly doing the same thing. But when I refer an action/reducer/service of shared module from a different module, it gives me a run time error like, ***Cannot find module './arc/app/shared/some-service' or its type corresponding declarations***

Comment: But there is no error in the file itself. When I F12 on the import declaration, it is taking me to that class in the shared module.

Comment: Can you try sharing the code somewhere like stackblitz or GitHub?